# EXTJS 4.2 - changing the key in Property Editor

Tags: extjs4.2

I am using EXTJS 4.2.1 and we have a requirement wherein the user should have an ability to edit the 'Key' in the Property Editor.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should just use an editable grid with 2 columns and hide the headers. The property grid is solely for modifying the value column.

Comment: I would have to write a lot of boiler plate code if I am using an editable Grid.  I would have to convert the key values returned from the property grid into Java properties.  This is achieved easily by a Property Grid (with the only exception of being able to change the key's).

Comment: It would be more code, but it's not a "lot", maybe an extra 10-20 lines. The property grid is keyed by the properties, so changing them dynamically isn't supported.

Comment: I am rewriting it using a editable grid.  After spending a lot of time on researching how to edit the key name, I feel it is easier to just rewrite it using a editable grid panel.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my answer.